# How to return field ncm for other model?

Tags: django, django-models, field

models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    ncm = models.CharField(max_length=8)
    product = models.CharField(_('Produto'), max_length=60, unique=True)

class SaleDetail(models.Model):
    sale = models.ForeignKey(Sale, related_name='sales_det')
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='product_det')
    quantity = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(_('quantidade'))

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.sale)

    def get_ncm(self):
        return self.'ncm'
```

template

```
<td>{{ item.get_ncm }} </td>
```

I need

```
<td>{{ product.ncm }} </td>
```

How to return ncm of product in SaleDetail template?

Comment: Shouldn't `get_ncm(self)` on `SaleDetail` return `self.product.ncm` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Template access

From the product:

```
{{ some_product.ncm }}
```

From the SaleDetail:

```
{{ some_sale_detail.product.ncm }}
```

### Python access

From the product:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    def get_ncm(self):
        return self.ncm
```

From the SaleDetail:

```
class SaleDetail(models.Model):
    def get_ncm(self):
        return self.product.ncm
```